# c# pass List through chain of dependences

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have class A with one-to-many to class B which has one-to-many to class C. How I can create List of class C in class A?

```
public class A 
{
    public virtual IList<B> Bs { get; set; }
    //  need List<C> Cs passed from Bs
}

public class B
{
    public virtual A A { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<C> Cs { get; set; }
 }

public class C
{
    public virtual B B { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: How do you want to get them - as a method or a readonly property (`{get;}`)? You can't have it writeable (`{get; set;}`), because you would need to put the item you are adding into a `B` somehow

Comment: Just the getter. kaveman answered the question already. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx) from LINQ, which flattens a "list of lists" into a single list.

```
public class A 
{
    public virtual IList<B> Bs { get; set; }

    //if you need an IList<C>
    public IList<C> Cs
    {
        get { return Bs.SelectMany(b => b.Cs).ToList(); }
    }  

    //if you need an IEnumerable<C>
    public IEnumerable<C> Cs
    {
        get { return Bs.SelectMany(b => b.Cs); }
    }    
}
```

Comment: It answers the question. Thank you.